# What does the "Control Module" setting in FlashPrint 5.1 do?

Tags: slicing, flashforge, flashprint

I don't understand the description of this setting in FlashPrint and have been unable to find a better description online. What does it do?

[image: Screenshot of FlashPrint settings with Control Module highlighted]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[On Reddit, someone pointed out](https://old.reddit.com/r/FlashForge/comments/p5dwrf/flashprint_5_release/h96cpuf/) that this likely refers to which items temperature is being adjusted by the tickbox above (and table below). It seems quite obvious now :-)